# The multiplication of the cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory

I came across a problem yesterday.The question is：
If $F_1(x,y)$ and $F_2(x,y)$ are two two-dimensional probability distribution functions , is $F_1(x,y)F_2(x,y)$ a two-dimensional  probability distribution function?
If this is true,please prove it.If this is not true,give a counterexample please.
I have no idea about that and I need some help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "probability distribution function"? This is not a standard term. The two standard terms are "cumulative distribution function" and "probability density function" - do you mean one of those?

Comment: Sorry,that is cumulative distribution function.

Comment: It should satisfy monotonicity and $$\lim_{x\to\infty,y\to\infty}F_1(x,y)=1$$$$\lim_{...}F_1(x,y)=0$$and the nonnegativity of the difference.\newline I think the most important thing is the nonnegativity of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative distribution function is a probability: if $F_1$ is the CDF of a pair $(A,B)$, then $$F_1(x,y) = \Pr[A \le x \text{ and }B \le y].$$ Similarly, if $F_2$ is the CDF of a pair $(C,D)$, then $$F_2(x,y) = \Pr[C \le x \text{ and }D \le y].$$
The product of two probabilities is a reasonable thing to think about if they are probabilities of independent events. If we say that $(A,B)$ are independent from $(C,D)$, then we have
$$
   F_1(x,y) F_2(x,y) = \Pr[A \le x \text{ and } B \le y\text{ and } C \le x\text{ and } D \le y].
$$
Now, is there a reasonable definition of $X$ and $Y$ such that "$X \le x\text{ and } Y \le y$" is the same event as "$A \le x \text{ and } B \le y\text{ and } C \le x\text{ and } D \le y$"?

Comment: It's not obvious and I have no idea about your method.

Comment: I am always trying to do this via basic property of the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't.

Comment: But $(A,B)$ may not be independent of $(C,D)$.

Comment: So what can you deduce by your way of solving?It seems that you have  not figured it out completely.

Comment: (1) We are free to define $(A,B)$ to be independent of $(C,D)$ here. (2) I am trying to guide you to a solution rather than telling you what the solution is.

Comment: I konw your intention,but I still do not  know how to preceed.Maybe I am so awkward.

Comment: Could you explain it in detail? Thanks very much.

Comment: Could I choose $X$,$Y$to be $\min(A,C)$,$\min(B,D)$respectively?In that way,$$\mathbb{P}(X\le x,Y\le y)=\mathbb{P}(A\le x,C\le x,B\le y,D\le y)$$I am looking forward to your reply!@ 
Misha Lavrov

Comment: Almost! You want $X \le x$ only if $A \le x$ **and** $C \le x$, so you want $X = \max\{A,C\}$ and $Y = \max\{B,D\}$.

Comment: Thanks very much！